# Gurobi Root Simplex Stuck after 20 minutes

Tags: solver, gurobi

I use GUROBI to solve a large MILP. The LP is solved in 3 minutes. After that the crossover begins it calculates about 20 minutes. Then it drops a variable from basis and does not give any console output for the next 2 hours.
I'm using the barrier method and I put crossover on -1 so that it is automatically chosen.

The log looks like this after 3 hours:

[image]

I have tried running it multiple times with the same thing happening.

Any ideas on how to fix that or am I just not waiting long enough?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your model has numerical issues; please read [Guidelines for Numerical Issues](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/10.0/refman/guidelines_for_numerical_i.html) in the Gurobi Reference Manual.